# SOAP: Namespace pointed to is not up anymore. Possible consequence?

Tags: soap, namespaces

I am modifying some legacy project using SOAP web services. I noticed that some of the URLs it is pointing to for some of the namespace are not working anymore (500). Any idea what the consequence would be?

Both the client and server seems to be working fine still, but I need to make a new client that consumes the WS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces may be in the form of a URL, but they do not represent a resource on the network. In many cases, there never *was* any resource at that location. It makes no difference at all.